# Angular html5 mode Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to ask you for help in this code.

I get **Error**  in console:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: category in categories, Duplicate key: string:<, Duplicate value: <

I don't know why  this code doesn't work:

```
category in categories track by $index
```

Like in this example https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Files source:

**public\views\categories.html**

```
<h3 class="heading">Category</h3>
<div ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <div class="categories">
        <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>{{category.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{category.description}}</p>
         <a href="/articles/category/{{category.name}}">Viwe Articels</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**categories.controller.js**

```
angular.module("kB")

.controller('CategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/categories').success(function(data) {
    $scope.categories = data;
});
}]);
```

**categories.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Category = require('../models/category');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
Category.getCategories(function(err,categories){
    if(err){
       console.log(err);
    }
res.json(categories);
   });
});
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
Category.getCategoryById(req.params.id, function(err,category){
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
res.json(category);
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**models/category.js**

```
var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
            type: String,
            index: true,
            required: true
          },
    description: {
            type: String
          }
});
```

**routis/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

uter.get('*', function (req, res) {
res.render('index')
})

module.exports = router;
```

in app.js

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

**Category Obejct**

```
{ getCategories: [Function],
  getCategoryById: [Function],
  getArticlesByCategory: [Function],
  createCategory: [Function] }
```

Comment: Please share your `categories` object.

Comment: { getCategories: [Function],
  getCategoryById: [Function],
  getArticlesByCategory: [Function],
  createCategory: [Function] }

Comment: why dont you log the categories and see whether you are getting the data then you can be sure that the problem is from your front end

Answer (score 1):

changing

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
```

to

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories track by $index">
```

should work if you haven't done it already.

Comment: It works, but after i refresh the page it becomes a JSON file

Answer (score 0):

Now it works well with:

```
 <div ng-repeat="category in categories track by $index">
```

If I have / or * in express:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index')
  });

 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index')
  });
```

but after i refresh the page it becomes a json file.